# Edit header in Typo3

Tags: header, typo3

I have a website that is running on Typo3 CMS, this was all setup by our developer, problem is he doesn't work for us anymore, all I want to do is change the url of our company logo located at the header section, I have basic knowledge of HTML and CSS, I manage to move things around in the backend, but I don't know how to change the url of our logo.

Comment: There are so many possibilities how your header is realized. This question cant be answered without you providing more technical details about how your templating is done in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your developer has set it in:

- Typoscript (e.g. PAGE TS)
- template-File (index.html in /filedmin or fileadmin/templates)
- As Content Element (at the top of the Tree)
- CSS
- A Mix of all of the Possibilities...

Perhaps a solution:
Type the current url of the Image in the Searchbox at Top of Backend.

Another Way to find out is via Firebug (Firefox).

Comment: Thank you brandelizer, searching the url at searchbox at the backend helped me find the location, thanks a lot!